# Which is the more efficient way to connect to a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, coding-style, data-access-layer

Having a disagreement with a coworker, and I at this point, I don't care who is right, I'm more curious which is the better solution so that I can use it going forward.

We have different ways to access a system.

**Option #1:**
Creates the database with the code below.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;

namespace Ivans.Healthcare.CommercialAccess.Data
{
    public abstract class DataAccess : DataHelperBase
    {
        public const int commandTimeout = 7200;
        private static Database m_db = null;
        public StringBuilder Status {get; set;}

        public DataAccess()
        {
            this.Status = new StringBuilder();

            if (m_db == null)
            {
                bool bIfRunsOnWebService = false;
                try
                {
                    if (DynamicConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebService"] != null)
                    {
                        bIfRunsOnWebService = true;
                    }
                }
                catch {}

                if (!bIfRunsOnWebService)
                {
                    m_db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(DataAccessResource.IDS_DB_ALIAS);
                }
                else
                {
                    m_db = CreateDatabase(DataAccessResource.IDS_WS_DB_ALIAS);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then everytime a stored procedure needs to be called, the method would contain something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<InquiryServiceType> GetActive(bool is5010)
{

    Database db = getDB();
    DbCommand dbCmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand(DataAccessResource.IDS_SP_SEL_InquiryServiceTypeData_ListServiceTypes);
    db.AddInParameter(dbCmd, DataAccessResource.IDS_SP_SEL_InquiryServiceTypeData_ListServiceTypes_Is5010Request, DbType.Boolean, is5010);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    db.LoadDataSet(dbCmd, ds, new string[] { DataAccessResource.IDS_TBL_InquiryServiceTypeData });

    return DataSetTranslator.TranslateInquiryServiceTypeDataSet(ds);
}
```

**Option 2**

This option is a bit more modular and was trying to create a generic database method.

```
    private Database currentDB;
private const int commandTimeout = 7200;

public DataAccess(Common.Enums.ConnectionString currentConnection)
{
    currentDB = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(currentConnection.ToDescription());
}

public IEnumerable<T> SelectMany<T>(string spName, params Param[] parameters) where T : IDataPopulate<T>, new()
{
    var storedProcedure = CreateStoredProcedureCommand(spName);
    AddParameters(storedProcedure, parameters);

    IDataReader myReader = null;
    IList<T> listOfItems = new List<T>();

    try
    {
        myReader = currentDB.ExecuteReader(storedProcedure);
        if (myReader == null)
        {
            return listOfItems;
        }

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            listOfItems.Add(new T().FillObject(myReader));
        }

        return listOfItems;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string message = string.Format("Error Message: {0}\r\nStored Procedure: {1}\r\n", ex.ToString(), spName);
        throw new Exception(message);
    }
    finally
    {
        DataAccessDisposal.DataReader(myReader);
        DataAccessDisposal.StoredProcedure(storedProcedure);
    }
}
```

Then calling the database would look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<InquiryServiceTypes> GetAll(int payerID)
{
    Param payerIdParam = new Param("@payerID", DbType.Int32, payerID);
    return dataAccess.SelectMany<InquiryServiceTypes>("dbo.proc_PayersInquiryServiceTypesSel", payerIdParam);
}
```

**Conclusion**

There are definitely things that are coded incorrectly in each of the sections. I'm pretty sure that there is a middle ground to be reached that is the most efficient code.

The code above has two points of inefficiency. The first is how it connects to the database in the first place. The second is once the data is returned, how do you deal with it. I'd love to discuss both, but feel that the first is more important for this point.

Thanks,
C

Comment: Performance test both approaches and get your own answer yourselves.

Comment: "really inefficient in that it first creates a datatabase" is subjective, btw

Comment: please make comments on the code here instead of editting it directly. (the p.s. was added by a different user) and I agree it is subjective. Why is it really inefficient? That is what I'm trying to learning. And they both happen to use CreateDatabase()

Comment: Oded - I've never done this before. Is there a preferred a resource that I could use beside just adding starttime/stoptime before and after each call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say simply: there are abstractions that do this already (and do it very well). If you can handle creating the connection then, for example, with [dapper-dot-net](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net):

```
return connection.Query<InquiryServiceTypes>(
        "dbo.proc_PayersInquiryServiceTypesSel",
        new { payerId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

which will write all the parameterisation and materialization for you in heavily cached IL. No need to write a complex `Fill` method or populate method, and very very fast (identical performance to writing all the ADO.NET reader code manually, but without the boring code and chance of typos).

Writing all those `Fill` methods manually is **not** efficient (for developer time).

Note in the above; the anonymous type is defining the parameters, i.e. it is saying "there is an int parameter called payerId, with the same value as was passed in". You could also have:

```
new { id = payerId, name = "abc", allData = true }
```

which would add `@id` (int) with the value from `payerId`, `@name` (nvarchar) with value `'abc'`, and `@allData` (bit) with value `1`.

---

Edit re the points in the comments:

- connection pooling is orthogonal since that is done automatically by default (with SQL server) as long as you release your connections promptly
- entlib adds, IMO, overhead without any good reason. The code talking to entlib is virtually identical to talking to raw ado.net, except with more bloat and indirection. I would avoid entlib unless you actually use something it does to make your life easier
- loading a dataset is always overhead; DataTable etc is complex - much more complex than loading a POCO model. Loading a dataset **just** so you can then use the dataset to load an object model is inefficient, and creates unnecessary garbage on the heap that needs to be collected, and has lots of steps anyway (adapters, etc), all of which take time
- the DataTable approach also demands fully reading a table, rather than non-buffered spooling (possible with a raw reader and iterator block); this may be significant if you have very large results
- of the two approaches presented, the second is IMO far preferable, but I **do not** like the interface; that is poor "separation of concerns" - the POCO's job is to represent a domain object, not to know about the database
- as noted above, there are options similar to the second option, that are **much less** work to implement / maintain, and don't introduce SoC issues; I would look at this with great interest
- such options also address more complex scenarios for you; multiple grids; horizontal joins (into sub-objects); etc

Comment: For the sake of this discussion, I realize that there are hundreds of options out there that we could use, but I'm curious about positives and negatives of the above code. I know there are things like connection pooling and heap management that I'm not that knowledgeable in. So I'm trying to learn and I don't just want to accept the other developers reason as the truth. 'cause he may be wrong.

Comment: I will agree that this is a much cleaner solution and will bring it up when we have our next architecture meeting.

Comment: thanks your comments in the edit is exactly what I'm looking for. The datatable to list is definitely wasteful. So to make sure that I'm clear in regards to Seperation of Concerns, the issue is that when I create the object, I have the fillmethod that would require the class to know exactly what the data is like in so that it can convert the datareader to the class. I see what you're saying, was so stuck on Open-Closed principle that I missed this one.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you only want read only access to iterate over the returned data then using a datareader will be more efficient both in terms of performance and memory usage.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978388.aspx for a performance comparison of data access techniques.

Would advise you take a look at using Entity Framework, Massive or PetaPoco though, as using one of these frameworks is likely to save you time and also make the code more readable/maintainable.

Comment: we are looking into Entity Framework, but don't have time to do a full rewrite of the system. Thanks for the link, checking it out now.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I think, the Dot net code i.e. application code must not be in any way coupled with the database. Reasons are:

1. If the method that is created above is designed for SQL Server then you are restricted with SQL Server. You must be able to switch the storage easily.
2. What if you need some more settings and restrictions while creating your database? You have to release another version because you have to amend the code.

Generic database methods will fail on most of the occasions and is very difficult to debug.

Comment: Most business soltions never switch database back-ends. Only a idiot would do so when you have trillions of records.

Comment: Ah, but HLGEM, that is just not true. Even if you stick with one DB product, they are all re-versioned every few years.

Comment: What if you are a company making a customised solution for a number of clients. Each client uses a different database that you need to incoorporate in within your solution? Will you use this approach then? Think big HLGEM. Broaden your mind!!